# How to connect to mongo replica cluster in elixir

Tags: mongodb, erlang, elixir, replicaset

I created a mongo replica set from which I am trying to connect with elixir. I created 3 mongo instance in replica set and gave hostnames in `/etc/hosts` so the thing is that everything is working fine in mongo terminal and I am able to connect properly with mongo replica set.
I wrote code in `NODE.JS` to fetch data from replica set using `mongodb` library and it is also working fine(It means configuration in mongo server and my local server is fine as much as I know ), but when I am trying to connect it through elixir it is throwing error when I am connecting to that replica set.

I am using following library to connect with it.

```
https://github.com/ankhers/mongodb
```

as in library author has suggested to use following configuration

```
{:ok, pid} = Mongo.start_link(database: "test", seeds: "hostname1.net:27017", "hostname2.net:27017")
```

which is throwing syntax error.

```
** (SyntaxError) iex:6: syntax error before: "hostname2.net:27017"
```

which is obvious as it is wrong.

When I am using this configuration

```
worker(Mongo, [[name: :mongo,database: "yatender", topology: "replica_set_no_primary",seeds: ["xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017","xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017","xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017"] ,pool: DBConnection.Poolboy]])
```

Note:I have changed host address as xxx so don't get confused with it.

```
GenServer #PID<0.1436.0> terminating
** (stop) exited in: GenServer.call(#PID<0.1410.0>, 
{:server_description, %{address: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017", arbiters: [], 
election_id: nil, error: nil, hosts: ["mongo.host1:27017", 
"mongo.host2:27017", "mongo.host3:27017"], 
last_update_time: -576460750248, last_write_date: %DateTime{calendar: 
Calendar.ISO, day: 26, hour: 6, microsecond: {0, 3}, minute: 47, month: 
7, second: 23, std_offset: 0, time_zone: "Etc/UTC", utc_offset: 0, 
year: 2017, zone_abbr: "UTC"}, max_wire_version: 5, me: 
"mongo.host3:27027", min_wire_version: 0, op_time: %{"t" => 
2, "ts" => #BSON.Timestamp<6446967716292067329>}, passives: [], 
primary: "mongo.host2:27017", round_trip_time: 240, set_name: 
"rs0", set_version: 4, tag_set: %{}, type: :rs_secondary}}, 30000)
```

when I use following configuration in worker

```
{:ok, pid} = Mongo.start_link(database: "yatender", seeds: ["xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017","xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017","xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017"])
```

this error comes

```
    [warn]  Logger dropped 999 OTP/SASL messages as it exceeded the amount of 500 messages/second                                                                                    
** (EXIT from #PID<0.1410.0>) exited in: GenServer.call(#PID<0.1415.0>, 
{:server_description, %{address: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017", arbiters: [], 
election_id: nil, error: nil, hosts: ["mongo.host1:27017", 
"mongo.host2:27017", "mongo.host3:27027"], 
last_update_time: -576460688733, last_write_date: %DateTime{calendar: 
Calendar.ISO, day: 26, hour: 6, microsecond: {0, 3}, minute: 58, month: 
7, second: 13, std_offset: 0, time_zone: "Etc/UTC", utc_offset: 0, 
year: 2017, zone_abbr: "UTC"}, max_wire_version: 5, me: 
"mongo.host1:27017", min_wire_version: 0, op_time: %{"t" => 2, 
"ts" => #BSON.Timestamp<6446970508020809729>}, passives: [], primary: 
"mongo.host2:27017", round_trip_time: 42, set_name: "rs0", 
set_version: 4, tag_set: %{}, type: :rs_secondary}}, 30000)
** (EXIT) time out
```

When I just directly connect to a standalone mongodb server which is not a 
part of replica set it works fine as this.

```
# Starts an unpooled connection
{:ok, conn} = Mongo.start_link(database: "test",hostname: Application.get_env(:api, :api_env)[:mongo_host])

# Gets an enumerable cursor for the results
cursor = Mongo.find(conn, "test-collection", %{})

cursor
|> Enum.to_list()
|> IO.inspect
```

So I am stuck here and I don't know what I am missing. Please someone guide me how I can approach this problem, where I am wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess using seeds is recommended way, but it's not the only way. Maybe you should try to connect to that replica set as if you were connecting to single node? (Just to make sure it works just right)

Comment: Are you sure every node is up? https://github.com/ankhers/mongodb/issues/144 Do you think this issue may be related?

Comment: everything is fine and I am able to do everything perfectly in node.js but I'm new in elixir so i'm stuck here.

Comment: This driver supposably has issues with replica set. Maybe you should ask author himself? Posting an issue on github seams like a good idea.

Comment: sure will do :) thanks a lot for help

Comment: And this should be syntacticaly correct `{:ok, pid} = Mongo.start_link(database: "test", seeds: ["hostname1.net:27017", "hostname2.net:27017"])`

Comment: yeah I tried this also but throwing error here too.. so posting on github only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after so many hit & trials
instead of server IP

```
{:ok, pid} = Mongo.start_link(database: "yatender", seeds: ["xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017","xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017","xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017"])
```

we have to give name of hosts

```
{:ok, pid} = Mongo.start_link(database: "yatender", seeds: ["mongo.host1:27017","mongo.host2:27017","mongo.host3:27017"])
```

we can also use poolboy with this.

Comment: This does not sound right. You should be able to connect to your cluster using a seed list of ip:port pairs. I was just able to do it on my own cluster. **disclaimer:** I am the current `mongodb` package maintainer.